# JavaScript Ajax and Mail/Ticket

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm working on some project which there is a Bootstrap modal it sending tickets but I want also send email to the same person at the same time. But I'm missing something I guess.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                            <form onsubmit="return false" id="new_message_form" autocomplete="off">
                                <input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="new_message">
                                <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" id="ticket_id" value="<?=$id;?>">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group no-margin">
                                            <textarea class="ckeditor" id="message_new" name="message_new"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-<?=$this->Configs->get_info("theme_buttons2");?>" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                                <button id="ticket_message_add" class="btn <?=$this->Configs->get_info("theme_buttons");?>">Send</button>
                            </form>
```

and it sends it to admin.js

```
    $("#ticket_message_update").click(function (){
    CKEDITOR.instances['message_update'].updateElement();
    $("#UpdateMessageModal").modal("hide");

    $.post(base_admin+"support", $("#update_message_form").serialize() ,function(data){

    var data= JSON.parse(data);

     if(data.update== 1){ 
$('#update_message_form')[0].reset();
location.reload();
}

  });
});
```

So here is the thing. I have fully working ajax form with php mail system.(PHPMailer on github) When I click send button it automatically sending email to target mail addresses. But when I try to merge the ticket and email system seems not working but in logic it should be.

I'm adding function on button/input fields

```
onclick="AjaxFunction();"

<button id="ticket_message_add" onclick="AjaxFunction();" class="btn <?=$this->Configs->get_info("theme_buttons");?>">Send</button>
```

and adding my script also;

```
<script>
                                function AjaxFunction() {
                                    var bilgi = {
                                        userid: $('#user').val(),
                                        ad: $('#ticket_id').val(),
                                        soyad: $('#message_new').val()
                                    }
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'post',
                                        url: 'gonder.php',
                                        data: {query: bilgi},
                                        success: function(result) {

                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            </script>
```

And it needs to send the variables to "gonder.php" right? But it doesn't. Apparently I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try to send the data like this:

```
 function AjaxFunction() {
    var bilgi = [{  
        userid: $('#user').val(),
        ad: $('#ticket_id').val(),
        soyad: $('#message_new').val()
    }];  

 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'gonder.php',
        data: {query: JSON.stringify(bilgi)},
        success: function(result) {

        }
      });
}
```

then on the server side:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($_POST["query"]);
// will echo the JSON.stringified - string:
echo $_POST["query"];
// will echo the json_decode'd object
var_dump($data);
//traversing the whole object and accessing properties:
foreach($data as $cityObject){
    echo "userid: " . $cityObject->userid. ", ad: " . $cityObject->ad. "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Hope it Helps